# react-router-dom useNavigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I have a component, where i have to call navigate to main page, but navigate is not working, where is my fall? I know that userName is changing but redirect doesn't happening
Index.js

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

App.js

```
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
    </Routes>
  )
```

Login.js

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const user = useSelector((store) => store.user);
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const onSubmitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_USER,
      payload: { login: user.login, password: user.password },
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(user.userName) {
      navigate("/login");
    }
  
  }, [user.userName])
```

Comment: Where are you dispatching userName ?

Comment: It's dispatching, i've checked

Comment: Put debugger in useEffect and check if it’s triggering the if condtion

Comment: This seems like it may be a redux issue and not a routing/navigation issue. What debugging have you done? Is the `FETCH_USER` action dispatched? Is the action handled? Is the redux store updated? Do you see `user` change via the selector? Is the `useEffect` hook triggered subsequently? Is the `user.userName` value what you expect? Please include all relevant code you have an issue working with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the case but try changing the order of your paths to this:

```
return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Switch>
  )
```

I had a similar thing before and somehow navigation was always navigating to the Home because path"/" was on top.

Also a small thing, I normally use the Routes with Switch. In my experience above structure should work

Comment: It seems the OP is using `react-router-dom@6`. The `Routes` component replaced the `Switch` component from RRDv5. You are correct though, in RRDv5 the route path order and specificity mattered. In RRDv6 it isn't since the routes use a path ranking system now.